# Indirect variable assignment in r

Tags: r, variable-assignment

Given strDate such as "20050831", I'd like to create a variable named "pr_20050831" and assign a data frame to it.  I'm trying to do this within a function to which strDate is being passed.  Thus I cannot just use `pr_20050831<-df`.  I'd like to create `varName<-paste("pr_",strDate,sep="")` and then assign an object NOT TO varName but to the variable contained in varName (hence indirect in my subject line).

I've tried such things as `paste("pr_",strDate,sep="")<-df` and `eval(paste("pr_",strDate,sep=""))<-df` and `eval(paste("pr_",strDate,sep="")<-df)`

Thank you.

Comment: The usual advice: Don't do that (though there are ways you can). Presuming that you have many such `strDate`s, you could put the assigned objects into a list, like `myvars <- list(); myvars[[strDate]] <- df` and later access them again with `myvars[[strDate]]`

Comment: @Frank's comment is very relevant -- this is almost never something you want to do outside of libraries.  Perhaps asking a more general question about what you're trying to accomplish would be more helpful.  That said, look at the help for `assign` if you decide that this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and I will take your advice.  I did find an answer to my question which is `assign(paste("pr_",strDate,sep=""),df)`.